# CSS Triangle with gradient background color

Tags: css

I've been playing around with triangle "hack" with css, but can't make it work with gradient background color.

```
.m--label {
    position: relative;
    font-size: .9em;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #E00000;
    line-height: 38px;
}

.m--label:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    border-top: 40px solid #E00000;
    border-right: 40px solid #2b2b2b;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #E00000;
}
```

If I change the `border-top` or `bordem-bottom` colors to gradient like this:

```
border-top: 40px solid  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,59,0,1) 100%);
```

it completely fades the triangle, so it appears like a simple box. Also, with this solution it would only work with Chrome. What could be the solution for this?

Comment: Please provide some information why downvoting, so that I can improve the question. Otherwise downvote is worth nothing. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried implementing the linear gradient with `-moz`, etc.?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Answer (score 1):

maybe a gradient background would be more easy to manage :

```css
.m--label {
    position: relative;
    font-size: .9em;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #E00000;
    line-height: 38px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent  calc(100% - 40px), rgba(224,0,0,1) calc(100% - 40px),rgba(255,59,0,1) calc(100% - 20px));
}
```

```html
<div class="m--label"></div>
```